# How do i filter a table in another form from a selected row in the first form?

Tags: database, entity-framework, datagridview

So i have 2 Forms. Both with DataGridViews. I want to take the ID from the selected row in the first form and filter the table in the second form so it only displays the data relevant to the selected row in the first form.

Heres some code that i have so far.
[Second half Half of code from Form 1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8PHz.png)

[First half of form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRjQ7.png)

Comment: I suggest reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no short answer for this question. You can do this in many different ways. To give you an idea with simple way; take instance to second form and keep it in variable inside the first form. Write method to second form something like you can pass SelectedRow information and when selection changed in datagridview, simple call the method with additional parameters.

As I said at the beginning, this isn't perfect way to do this. But suggest this method to solve your problem. Happy coding.